# Syncing contents in instances in Auto scaling group under load balenecer

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, cloud, load-balancing, autoscaling

I have EC2 instances with WordPress in an auto scaling group behind a load balancer. It is created from my customized AMI with everything done. Suppose a new user in WordPress writes a post or uploads photos. How can I sync those content in all my instances in the ASG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where your data is being stored. For example, if the WordPress posts are stored in RDS and the photos are stored in S3 (a pretty robust setup), the EC2 instances would always be looking at the same data, so they would always be in sync.

Comment: thx tom......so if i sync the html contents to s3 and back using cron tab...whether it will cause too much latency....or is it enough?

Comment: Ideally your WordPress site would just be storing and retrieving things like photos in S3, and not at all in the local file system (same for posts: all in RDS, nothing stored locally). If you have no option but to store locally for some reason, you could consider [AWS EFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html) so that what appears to be a local directory to WordPress is actually an NFS mount that provides all EC2 instances with the same data.

Comment: thx tom for your reply....How could i use EFS as i have multiple autoscaled instances and the number of instances increases as cpu utilization increases(rule that i had given in asg).

Comment: After creating an EFS file system, you'd probably want to configure the EC2 instances to mount it automatically on start-up (with [cloud-init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mount-fs-auto-mount-onreboot.html#mount-fs-auto-mount-on-creation), for example). Then you could configure WordPress to save things to whatever directory EFS is mounted as. Keep in mind that all the instances will be accessing the same file system simultaneously, which could cause file locking and race condition issues depending on how you're accessing it.

Comment: Thx Tom for your solution.